# Does this series diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the series $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\arctan \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}/2}{1/2+k}\right)}$$ diverge ?

This is part of a larger problem, and I am trying to prove the following: we start with the point $\omega = e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}$ and consider the points $\omega, \omega + 1, \omega + 2,...$ and I want to prove that $Arg(\omega) + Arg(\omega+1) + Arg(\omega+2) + ...$ diverges.

Comment: If $f$ is any function such that $f'(0)\ne 0,$ and $a_k$ is a sequence such that $ka_k$ has a finite nonzero limit, then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f(a_k)\,\,\text {diverges}.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that, by [On the arctangent inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270277/on-the-arctangent-inequality), $\arctan(x)\geq\frac{x}{2}$ for $x\in [0,1]$.
Hence, for $k\geq 1$,
$${\arctan \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}/2}{1/2+k}\right)}\geq \frac{\sqrt{3}/2}{1+2k}.$$
What may we conclude?

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$\arctan \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}/2}{1/2+k}\right)\sim \frac{\sqrt{3}/2}{1/2+k}$$

then refer to limit comparison test with $\sum \frac 1 k$.